# MVC bad url error handling

Tags: php

I´m making a tiny MVC framework for learning purpose.

I have a file and a class called load which is in my model folder. It reads the requested file name and checks if the file is in the views folder and returns the correct file.
The problem I´m having is that I´m trying to make a handling for bad urls so that if the requested file/url does not excist you are directed to the index.php page in the views folder...

I have an if statement inside the function that checks if the file exists and I thought I could just write an else statement requiring the index.php file incase the file was not found...
But this doesn´t work. All I´m getting is a white blank page when I type in an non existing page even I´f I try echo something in the else statement...

Does anyone know what´s missing or what I´m doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Added mainController class

This is what the hole load class looks like:

```
<?php
/* model/load.php
 */
class load
{

     /* This function takes parameter 
     * $file_name and match with file in views.
     */

    function view($file_name, $data = null)
    {
        if (is_readable('views/' . $file_name)) {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                extract($data);
            }
            require 'views/' . $file_name;
        } else {

         //This is where I thought I could require the index.php file...        
        }
    }

}
```

And in my controller folder I have a mainController class sending the files to the load file.
This is what the mainController class looks like:

```
<?php
/* controller/main.php
 *
 */
class mainController
{
    public $load;
    public $urlValues;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
        $url = explode('/', trim($url['path'], '/'));
        $this->urlValues = array('controller' => $url[1]);

        //Index page
        if ($this->urlValues['controller'] == "index.php") {

        $key = array("key" => "");

        $this->load = new load();
        $this->load->view('index.php', $key);   
        } 
        //Register page
        if ($this->urlValues['controller'] == "register.php") {

        $this->load = new load();
        $this->load->view('register.php');   
        } 
        //Home page
        if ($this->urlValues['controller'] == "home.php") {

        $this->load = new load();
        $this->load->view('home.php');   
        } 

    }        
}
```

Comment: A blank white page usually means you don't have error reporting enabled (or atleast are not displaying them) and something went wrong. Enable error reporting. `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment! I haven´t had problems with error handling before. The white blank page only shows when I request a page that does not exist... I tried inserting your error code in my bootstrap/index file but it still is a blank page... @FDL

Comment: If you are still getting a white screen the error log can be helpful. On linux this is usually found in the /var/log folder or on mac in the folder of your LAMP distribution.

Comment: If you `echo $file_name;` at the top of the method (before the `if`) do you get the expected outcome for `$file_name`?

Comment: I´m only getting a blank page when I try to visit a non existing page. So it seems there is something missing in my else statement! @BenWaine

Comment: That works fine if when I visit an existing page eg. home.php but it doesn´t work if I try with a non existing e.g ho.php @FDL

Comment: make sure to add the error reporting part at the top of your main file (your main index.php in this case) because if not, it won't display the errors which happened before that line. Also, instead of checking for the file existence (use `file_exists()` instead of `is_readable()` btw) try to have a router class, normally the MVC systems are done that way, having some advantages, ie naming the file whatever you want, not having to match the url part, or having multilingual url's

Comment: Do you have any `.htaccess` (Apache mod-rewrite) rules in place to route everything to a front controller? It doesn't look like the problem is with your `load` class, but something earlier in the process.

Comment: Yep, everything goes thru the main index.php file in the root folder! @FDL

Comment: Why does model layer load template?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the file which calls `load->view()`?

Comment: I just added the class mainController which I have in the controller folder! Whe I create a new page in the view folder I add it to this page so that it can send the requested file to load... @FDL

Comment: Now I see the problem, you are only ever calling `$this->load->view()` when the `if` statements in `mainController` match. You need to call it even if none of the pages match, or have it default to `index.php`. You should just call `$this->load->view($this->urlValues['controller']);` in all scenarios.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! I tried leaving another if statement in the mainController empty and see if it loads view anyways but didn´t work. Any idea how to make it call the load even when wrong file is requested?@FDL

Comment: I've added an answer, I don't think you need the `if`s but you can add them back in where the `// ifs go here` comment is if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you are only calling the `view` method when the controller matches, and therefore it never gets executed. Try something like this, and work from there:

```
<?php
/* controller/main.php
 *
 */
class mainController
{
    public $load;
    public $urlValues;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
        $url = explode('/', trim($url['path'], '/'));
        $this->urlValues = array('controller' => $url[1]);

        // ifs go here

        $this->load = new load();
        $this->load->view($this->urlValues['controller']);  
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean! That really helped!

Comment: I don´t even need the ifs then? The class gets really long if there is alot of pages in the views folder if I were to add ifs for all of them... This way is much better!